# NBSP placeholder no longer displays output

Tags: javascript, html

I have several web pages that use " " as a placeholder for javascript function output to display a button label. For example, the following is the html that displays the output if the 'clock()' function,

```
<div id="clock" class="sidebar"><a href="http://achan2.lanl.gov/timetool.php">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

This one displays 'Login' until the 'log()' function is called, then changes the label to 'Logout',

```
<div id="login" class="sidebar"><a href="#" onclick="log()">&nbsp;</a></div>
```

The javascript references the IDs to direct the output to the labels. Both of these were working until a few days ago, but now are just blank. No label is displayed. Nothing obvious has changed. No updates to the system, etc.  The server is running Ubuntu 16.04 lts and apache2 web server.

I have no idea why these would just quit working or where to begin looking for the problem. I have similar code running on a separate server that still works.  Are there any workarounds / alternative methods that would produce the output I want?

edit:

Here is the javascript as requested:

```
function clock() {
    var time = new Date(); //get the date

    //find what day of the year it is
    var start = new Date(time.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
    var day = Math.floor((time - start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));

    var offset = time.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

    if ((time.getHours() + offset) > 23) { day + 1; }

    //get the fraction part of the day
    var hour = time.getUTCHours() / 24;
    var minute = time.getUTCMinutes() / 1440;
    var sec = time.getUTCSeconds() / 86400;
    var fraction = hour + minute + sec;

    //display
    $('#clock a').html((day + fraction).toFixed(4));

    //change clock fontsize to fit well
    var width = $('#clock').css('width');
    var size = parseInt(width) / 4.75;
    size = size + 'px';

    $('#clock').css({'font-size':size});
}



/*makes either a login popout or logs someone out*/
function log() {
    if ($('#login').html() == "Login") {
        window.open("./login.html", "_blank","width=1000,height=500");
    }
    else { logout(); }
}
```

Comment: Try posting your javascript also as that is what is changing the HTML.

Comment: There are several issues here, but none related to your `html` no longer correctly outputting the text. (Things I would change: `onclick` to `addEventListener`, and `$('#login').html() == "Login"` is just a very... specific way to do it. Store a variable.) Maybe turn this into a snippet (the `</>` button in edit) and see if the issue persists in your minimal example on SO.

Comment: I've figured this out.  There was a ```$(document).ready(function()``` block missing from the beginning of the js file.  I found it by reviewing the revision history.  Works now as it was.